# Dirac delta-function integral in Kerson-Huang

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory, dirac-delta-distributions

I found a portion in Kerson Huang "Statistical Mechanics" book, in *Page No :  61*, where they have performed an integral over a delta function and got the last equation (given at the last in this question). I have given below the equation from where they have deduced the last equation. The equations in the book are *Eq.3.31* and *Eq.3.32* respectively.

Can someone please help me by proving/guiding how to derive at that equation. I am really unable to derive it. Your help will be appreciated.

The *Eq.3.31* is:-

$$\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\bigg)_{\rm collision}~=~\bar{R}-R=\int d^{3} p_{2}~ d^{3} p_{1}^{\prime}~ d^{3} p_{2}^{\prime}~ \delta^{4}\left(P_{f}-P_{i}\right)\left|T_{f i}\right|^{2}\left(F_{1'2'}-F_{12}\right)$$

Statement in the book after the  above  equation:

> where $F_{12}=F\left(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{p}_{1}, \mathbf{p}_{2}, t\right)$. Note that we can integrate over the vector $\mathbf{P'}_{1}$ and the magnitude $p_{2}$, so that the differential cross section appears in the integrand of (3.30):

The final equation that is given is (i.e. *Eq.3.32*):

$$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right)_{\rm collision}=\int d^{3} p_{2}~ d \Omega\left|\mathbf{v}_{1}-\mathbf{v}_{2}\right|(d \sigma / d \Omega)\left(F_{1^{\prime} 2^{\prime}}-F_{12}\right)$$

I can't prove *Eq.3.32* from *Eq.3.31* and I really want to know the prove since I feel it is necessary to understand it before proceeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to formulas (3.18) and (3.23). Also, take into account the remark about normalization at the end of page 59.

Comment: Yes Sir, I tried using them, but can't solve it. If possible, can you please help a little bit?

I am an undergrad, so kerson huang is getting a little bit confusing for me, but this equation really intrigued me, so I really want to know about it. So, can you please help a little bit?

Some help on how to progess will really help me.

Comment: Sir, I tried again today but couldn't solve it. I found the usage of Rutherford scattering involving the expressions $I\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}d\Omega$ and $I = n|v_1-v_2|$ but couldn't solve it. Can you kindly help me with some hints/steps?